# JLabel won't work with ButtonHandler

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jtextfield

For my assignment I have to create  a frame-based application that allows the user to specify RGB values in three text fields, and, when a button is pressed, displays my name and registration number in the chosen colour. I believe all my code is correct so far however it appears that there is an issue in the part that changes the colour.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;



public class ex1 extends JFrame {
JLabel label;
JTextField r, g, b;

public ex1() {
    //panels to hold information
    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel upperPanel = new JPanel();

    //fields that will hold the colour values
    r = new JTextField("Red", 10);
    g = new JTextField("Green", 10);
    b = new JTextField("Blue", 10);

    //add to frame
    bottomPanel.add(r);
    bottomPanel.add(g);
    bottomPanel.add(b);
    add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(upperPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    label = new JLabel("CE203 Assignment 1, submitted by:");
    label.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
    JButton button = new JButton("Enter");
    upperPanel.add(label);
    bottomPanel.add(button);
    button.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler(this));
}

public JLabel getLabel() {
    return label;
}

class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
    private ex1 assignment1;
    public ButtonHandler(ex1 assignment1) {
        this.assignment1 = assignment1;
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int r1 = Integer.parseInt(assignment1.r.getText());
        int g1 = Integer.parseInt(assignment1.g.getText());
        int b1 = Integer.parseInt(assignment1.b.getText());
        assignment1.getLabel().setForground(new Color(r1, g1, b1));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new ex1();
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(ex1.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

If anyone could show me what is going wrong and how I can fix it, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ignore the IDE when it is reporting compilation errors!

```
assignment1.getLabel().setForground(new Color(r1, g1, b1));
```

Should be:

```
assignment1.getLabel().setForeground(new Color(r1, g1, b1));
```

#### Other tips

1. Instead of:

   ```
   frame.setSize(400, 400); // random guess at required size
   ```

   have:

   ```
   frame.pack(); // calculates the required size
   ```
2. In real world programming, the user would lynch a programmer for offering 3 text fields when one `JColorChooser` is vastly superior.

Comment: I cannot believe how stupid I was! Literally facepalmed when I saw your comment haha, Thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: Ah thanks for the heads up, Ill try that in the future. Unfortunately  the assignment was to let the user choose the colour by entering the rgb values in 3 three separate text fields so it was up to the lecturer in this case

Comment: *"it was up to the lecturer in this case"* Yep, I guessed that from the question (which was very informative & clear - good work!). I think the instructor needs to improve the focus / quality of their exercises though. There are realistic situations where, as programmers, we'd need to parse integers, but this is not one of them.